# my log file too big and is the log file related with hack or backdoors?

Tags: logging

my log file too big (especially the access-log file) and is it hack or backdoor program?

my hosting stopped my host and they said your log file too big, you have to check your program may be there is some leaks in your program, but i do not think so. but not sure yet.
the truth my log file increases rapidly so much everyday.
especially the access-log file too big.

and i could not control the log file setting via Apache etc. , because mine is shared host. not allowed, but i can set some php.ini, but it does not help me.

anyone could analyses my access-log file content? and give me any solution. is there any hack or something else? or not?

the log is mostly 99% content is likes this:

```
66.249.74.126 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:10 +0800] "GET /koru.php?tur=20&id=72258 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
220.181.89.132 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:16 +0800] "GET /koru_kk.php?turi=4&id=136758 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
173.199.119.35 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:17 +0800] "GET /koru.php?tur=4&id=77653 HTTP/1.1" 302 63
173.199.119.35 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:18 +0800] "GET /koru.php?tur=14&id=91466 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
66.249.74.121 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:21 +0800] "GET /koru.php?id=114867 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
124.117.229.10 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:25 +0800] "GET /logo/elarna.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 4531
66.249.74.118 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:25 +0800] "GET /koru.php?id=114884 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
220.181.89.132 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:26 +0800] "GET /koru_kk.php?id=153800 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
182.118.20.236 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:26 +0800] "GET /koru_kk.php?id=148813&tur=31 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
66.249.74.122 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:28 +0800] "GET /koru.php?tur=19&id=97151 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
66.249.74.126 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:32 +0800] "GET /koru_kk.php?tur=3&id=131614 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
66.249.74.120 - - [26/Jun/2013:01:08:36 +0800] "GET /koru.php?id=114831 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
```

and the error log is often like this:

```
[Wed Jun 26 00:33:47 2013] [error] [client 198.74.231.14] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/robots.txt
[Wed Jun 26 00:33:49 2013] [error] [client 79.142.93.163] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:35:14 2013] [error] [client 222.81.42.192] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:36:02 2013] [error] [client 120.70.74.87] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:36:12 2013] [error] [client 147.30.71.68] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:36:15 2013] [error] [client 110.156.165.93] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:36:51 2013] [error] [client 46.227.184.117] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 26 00:37:01 2013] [error] [client 46.227.184.117] File does not exist: /var/www/virtual/nigmet/home/wwwroot/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt file does not exist is related to crawlers (like google indexer) reaching your website and trying to see what pages are allowed for crawling. Add robots.txt to your website to prevent that error.

As for the rest it seems you have somewhere some links that point to a favicon.ico that is not found and any time someone tries to access them, A LOT of errors are produced. Look at your links and see which ones are broken and fix them. Thus you'd reduce the errors and the size of your log.

Other than that activity does not seem malicious.

Comment: i could solve the robots.txt and favicon problem. but do not understand the access-logs on the above. the links pages are opens smoothly, no problem,, but log getting too big.. thanks

Comment: Even though links open smoothly somewhere in your page you have an <img> tag (maybe) that points to favicon, which is invalid. Look at your sources.

As for the access logs, we can't tell if they are malicious or not, without given the context (what is koru.php, are the IDs valid, etc...